# WebService return a XML/JSON file

Tags: java, xml, json, web-services

I require to write a simple java webservice that could show its output in the form of a XML/JSON file.

For example the user will click a link or a button, and a simple SQL statement would get executed `SELECT * FROM PERSON` and the result of the above SQL query should be displayed in the form a XML/JSON file.

I have googled this several times but failed to find a suitable tutorial or a sample code. Can some one help me by providing a sample code or a tutorial that would help me.

Comment: [an example using Spring 3](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=604)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following with **JAX-RS**:

```
package org.example;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="CustomerService",
                        type=PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)
    EntityManager entityManager;


    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    @Path("{id}")
    public Customer read(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Customer.class, id);
    }

}
```

**Full Example**

- [Part 1 - The Database](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-15.html)
- [Part 2 - Mapping the Database to JPA Entities](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-25.html)
- [Part 3 - Mapping JPA entities to XML (using JAXB)](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-35.html)
- [Part 4 - The RESTful Service](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-45.html)
- [Part 5 - The Client](http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/08/creating-restful-web-service-part-55.html)