# JSON widget in GWT

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gxt

I'm developing a GWT app.And to be clear , i'm totally new to GWT,Web development and stuffs.I have a requirement in my GWT app, to get a JSON input.I should provide a JSON editor kind of UI , so that the user can enter the JSON data.Please help me on how can i do this, and also suggest some widgets which would suit my requirement.Thanks!.

Answer (score 1):

First try to learn, what are web services, how to write web services in java that return JSON. You can find several tutorials online.

[WebService return a XML/JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229718/webservice-return-a-xml-json-file)

http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program (Uisng Spring)

Then, after try to integrate yout GWT project to server. You can find detail here
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GWT/article.html

Note: JSON is data format, used for communication between client an server. Earlier we used XML for the same, but JSON is more lightweight

[What is JSON and why would I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it)